# Jump out of quotes in VIM insert mode?

Tags: vim

I'm using the delimitMate plugin to get autowrapping quotes.  How can I step out of these quotes while in insert mode?  Not opposed to key mapping.

Comment: Do you mean something like hit the right arrow key and you're out?

Comment: what do you mean by not opposed to key mapping - you can always type `<right>` i think - or `<esc>a`. the first one is quite convenient with my keyboard layout (neo2), the other one is preferred by those who remapped <esc> to the capslock-button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While in Insert mode, press <kbd>Ctrl-o</kbd>(lowercase) immediately followed by <kbd>A</kbd>(uppercase).
You will be taken to end of current line and continue to be in Insert mode.

Hope that helps.

EDIT: In case you wish to step out of the quotes and land immediately to the right of the ending quote: while in Insert mode, press <kbd>Ctrl-o</kbd>(lowercase) immediately followed by <kbd>f"</kbd>(f followed by quotes) and then the <kbd>right</kbd> arrow key. You can assign a key map to this combination.